# How to trace basic LUA errors?

Tags: lua

I'm a beginner at LUA so I'm having some trouble with it. I'm using the code for a Minecraft mod called Computercraft, but to me it's a great introduction to programming.

I've been searching the web to find out why my code of not even 26 lines is failing, but I couldn't find it sadly.

Here's the code:

```
monitor = peripheral.wrap("right")
monitor.clear()
monitor.setCursorPos(1,1)
monitor.setTextScale(1)
monitor.print("Current mode:")
monitor.setCursorPos(1,3)
monitor.print("Dust gaat naar furnace")
redstone.setOutput(back,false)
print("Dust gaat automatisch naar de furnace toe")
print("Wil je dat de dust naar de chest gaat in plaats van de furnace?")
write()
while input == ja
do
  print("Oke :)")
  redstone.setOutput(back,true)
  monitor.clear()
  monitor.setCursorPos(1,1)
  monitor.print("Current mode:")
  monitor.setCursorPos(1,3)
  monitor.print("Dust gaat naar chest")
end
else
  print("Okeuu dan niet jongee")
end
```

I know that I have used 'end' 2 times. This is because I get an error when I remove one.

The error I get when I run the program is:

```
bios:14: [string ".temp"]:22: '<eof>' expected.
```

[The error I get when I remove the first 'end'.](http://prntscr.com/gcx6za)

[The error I get when I remove the second 'end'.](http://prntscr.com/gcx77h)

**EDIT**
Okay well after some advice i managed to get rid of the error. 
Thanks to all the people that responded! c:
Now i got an other error though lol. 
As suggested i made a new post about it: [Basic LUA problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894188/basic-lua-problems)

Comment: Post your errors as text.  Not pictures.

Comment: Probably, you want to use "if" instead of "while"?  `if input == ja then ... else ... end`

Comment: I'd say that the new problem is a matter for another question; you should revert the edit, mark the answer as accepted and create a new question for the new problem.

Comment: @MatteoItalia will do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The :22: is telling you that the error has occurred around line 22 of the script, which is the **else**. If you have a look at the Lua reference guide you will see that **else** belongs with an **if** statement, not a **while** statement.

Your code should probably be as follows, as a while doesn't make sense here

```
if input == ja
then
  ... code ...
else
  ... other code ...
end
```

Comment: i get another error: ".temp:5: attempt to call nil"

Comment: @Ynk - Probably, `monitor.print` is `nil`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff yep, read that on another post. Changed it to monitor.write and that seemed to get rid of that error, now onto the next error lol