# Basic LUA problems

Tags: lua, computercraft

I'm using ComputerCraft, a Minecraft mod that adds computers, monitors, modems and so on, which can be programmed using Lua scripts.

http://www.computercraft.info/wiki/Main_Page

While running my script I get this error: "bios:171: bad argument: string expected, got nil".

I dont understand because it says line 171 even though my code doesn't exceed 30 lines.. Can somebody explain?

```
monitor = peripheral.wrap("right")
monitor.clear()
monitor.setCursorPos(1, 1)
monitor.setTextScale(1)
monitor.write("Current mode:")
monitor.setCursorPos(1, 3)
monitor.write("furnace")
redstone.setOutput("back", false)
print("blablabla")
write()
if input == ja then
  print("k")
  redstone.setOutput("back", true)
  monitor.clear()
  monitor.setCursorPos(1, 1)
  monitor.write("blabla")
else
  print("u sux")
end
```

help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: we don't know, what is 'peripheral'

Comment: Yes, without knowing `peripheral` it is almost impossible to guess but just as a guess `write()` take a look at this command

Comment: @JacekCz  http://computercraft.info/wiki/Peripheral_(API)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You invoked an error in bios.lua which implements functions you can use in your script. Like `write`.

If we take a look into [bios.lua](https://github.com/Reddy360/Computercraft-Files/blob/master/bios.lua) we see that line 171 is actually part of the implementation of `write`.

It says: `while string.len(sText) > 0 do`, where `sText`

is the input argument to `function write( sText )` in line 154.

There is no proper error handling or default value for the case that `sText` is `nil`. The programmer did a sloppy job here.

In that case `string.len(sText)` in line 171 will causes the error you received.

In order to fix that you have to either remove the empty call to `write`, which is equivalent to `write(nil)` or you have to provide some input string.

`write("something")` will not cause any error. If you want to print an empty string just call `write("")`.